# Common link for current location in google maps for ios and android using html

Tags: android, html, ios, mobile, currentlocation

I can't seem to find a common answer anywhere. It seems like there isn't a way to support both Android and iPhone for links opening in their native maps application with their current location set.

From what I've been able to find, the iPhone does it like this:

```
saddr=Current%20Location
```

and android you can just leave "saddr" blank. I'm not even thinking of BlackBerries yet. I suppose there is probably a way to do this with JavaScript, but it don't think it should be that complicated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For now what I'm doing is using html5 geolocation to grab the latitude and longitude instead relying on the OS to interpret the current location.

HTML:

```
 <a id="directions" class="callout" href="http://maps.google.com/maps?daddr=address">
```

JavaScript:

```
$('#directions').bind('click', function (e) {
    var href = $(this).attr('href');
    if (navigator.geolocation) {
        e.preventDefault();
        navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function (position) {
            geoLink(position.coords.latitude, position.coords.longitude, href);
        });
    }

    function geoLink(lat, log, href) {
        var location = href + '&saddr=' + lat + ',' + log;
        window.location.href = location;
    }
```